# Creating out of bounds random number row and column for 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, random

I'm trying to put an array of String into an array of 2d char diagonally. I'm having an issue producing the range of my random number so that it would be in the indexes of my 2D array. My code works but sometimes it would break, giving a "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 60".

useWords is an array of String that the user enter and puzzleBoard is a 2d array of 60 rows and 30 columns.

```
for (int i = 0; i < userWords.length; i++) {
        int r = rand.nextInt(60); 
        int c = rand.nextInt(puzzleBoard[r].length - userWords[i].length());
         for (int j = 0; j < userWords[i].length(); j++) {
                 puzzleBoard[r+j][c+j] = userWords[i].charAt(j); // -j-j = dia right backward || +j+j= dia right forward || -j+j dia forward || +j-j dia backward
         }
      }
```

This is the output *if* the code doesn't break.

[image: This is the output *if* the code doesn't break]

Comment: Now is a good time to start learning how to debug a program.  If you are not using an IDE (Integrated Development Environment), I would suggest installing one ( such as Eclipse).  A little extra time will save you many hours in the long-run. THere are many tutorials - https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your code:

```
1    for (int i = 0; i < userWords.length; i++) {
2            int r = rand.nextInt(60); 
3            int c = rand.nextInt(puzzleBoard[r].length - userWords[i].length());
4            for (int j = 0; j < userWords[i].length(); j++) {
5                puzzleBoard[r+j][c+j] = userWords[i].charAt(j); // -j-j = dia right backward || +j+j= dia right forward || -j+j dia forward || +j-j dia backward
6            }
7        }
8    }
```

The value for `r + j` in line 5 can easily become larger than 59, as `r` by itself can already be 59. That way, your array will become out of bounds, hence the `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 60`.

You could use `(r + j) % 60` as a solution to continue at the left side of the board.